# Download files in ember: using Ember-cli-file-saver

Tags: ember.js, filesaver.js

It might be plain ignorance from my part but I have only managed to download a file generated by the api using the model method mention in the documentation. Using a component I am quite blind.

The specific question would be: where do I pass the mention `arraybuffer:true` to the application adapter or to a custom ajax request? Do you have a working example?

Here is a simple try using an ajax service:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import FileSaverMixin from 'ember-cli-file-saver/mixins/file-saver';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend(FileSaverMixin, {
  tagName: 'div',
  ajax: service(),
  store: service(),
  click() {
    this.get('ajax').request('/excel', {
      options: {
        arraybuffer: true
      }
      }
    ).then((content) => {
      console.log(content);
      this.saveFileAs(this.get('filename'), content, this.get('contentType'));
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
});
```

And this is my adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';
import AdapterArrayBufferMixin from 'ember-cli-file-saver/mixins/adapter-arraybuffer-mixin';
import ENV from 'efac-front/config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(
  DataAdapterMixin,
  AdapterArrayBufferMixin,
  {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:token',
    namespace: 'api',
    host: ENV.host
  }
);
```

I keep getting an error of `SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0...` because it is trying to interpret an array buffer or binary response as json data.

I very much appreciate any light you can throw here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it was super easy, but not very well documented. I just needed to add the `dataType` key to my ajax request like this:

```
this.get('ajax').request('/excel', {
      dataType: 'arraybuffer',
      options: {
        arraybuffer: true
      }
      }
    ).then((content) => {
      this.saveFileAs('reporte-asistencia.xlsx', content, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

It can also be done with `dataType: 'blob'`.